# NET5 Kestrel issue keeping connection id alive on load balanced servers

Tags: c#, server, .net-5, kestrel

I have a simple self-hosted REST API NET5 service and when I deploy it on the load balanced servers I see this in the logs (and it repeats every almost second)

```
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:14,474 [4] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAT" accepted.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:14,474 [9] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAT" started.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:14,474 [9] Sockets - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAT" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection."
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:14,475 [9] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAT" disconnecting.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:14,475 [9] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAT" stopped.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:15,137 [4] Sockets - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAU" received FIN.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:15,137 [4] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAU" accepted.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:15,138 [5] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAU" started.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:15,138 [5] Sockets - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAU" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection."
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:15,138 [5] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAU" disconnecting.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:15,138 [5] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAU" stopped.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:19,473 [4] Sockets - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAV" received FIN.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:19,473 [4] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAV" accepted.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:19,474 [5] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAV" started.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:19,474 [5] Sockets - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAV" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection."
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:19,474 [5] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAV" disconnecting.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:19,474 [5] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LAV" stopped.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:20,169 [4] Sockets - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LB0" received FIN.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:20,169 [4] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LB0" accepted.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:20,169 [13] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LB0" started.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:20,169 [13] Sockets - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LB0" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection."
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:20,170 [13] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LB0" disconnecting.
DEBUG 2021-09-01 13:56:20,170 [13] Kestrel - Connection id "0HMBDE70O3LB0" stopped.
```

This doesn't happen on the local machine and on a clustered server. Any idea what it can be and how to solve it?

Thanks, regards!